# Fitting data to a logistic function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logistic-regression

I've spent my whole entire weekend struggling with this problem. If we are given a set of data and are asked to fit it into a logistic equation:

$\frac{dP}{dt} = bP(\frac{a}b-P)$, where a and b is asked to be identified.

So the general solution I'd found from doing partial fraction was $\frac{Ae^{at}a}{1+Ae^{at}b}$ which hopefully is correct since I spent so much time on it. :')

I then found what A was at the initial point by replacing in the $P(0) = 1329$, so $A = \frac{(1329)}{(a-1329b)}$

Then I used another datapoint $P(1)=1976.89$ and rearranged it so that it equals $A = \frac{1796.89}{ae^a-1769.89e^ab}$. However I got stuck there since I tried to let both equations equal to each other like so:

$\frac{1796.89}{ae^a-1769.89e^ab}=\frac{(1329)}{(a-1329b)}$

But I tried it and... really should have known that it was not going work. I was planning on using another datapoint but I don't know if it's possible to solve if it's in the format of  $\frac{1796.89}{ae^a-1769.89e^ab}=\frac{(1329)}{(a-1329b)}$ = another long equation.

Kinda given up on it now since I wasted a weekend but how would you guys go about with this question.

Comment: Are you required to do this manually, or can you use a computer with a program that does linear or even non-linear fitting? The pairs $(P,P'/P)$ follow a line in the exact solution, use estimates for $P'$ and do linear regression. Or do a function that maps $(A,a,b)$ to the values at the time stamps and pass it to a non-linear curve-fitting procedure.

Comment: I have to do it manually since I wasn't taught about using any computer or anything, so I'm assuming I can't

Comment: How much data do you have to fit the logistic curve against? Only the two data points or much more?

Comment: I have quite a lot (~10ish) but I don't think I need to use all of them.

Comment: If you plot these points, do you see the shape of a sigmoid curve? Can you identify the symmetry center and the slope of the curve there?

Comment: @NLT. Why don't you edit in your question the data ( the coordinates of the points) ?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have data in the form $D = \{\{t_1,p_1\},\{t_2,p_2\},\cdots,\{t_n,p_n\}\}$

as the logistic curve is

$$
p(t) = \frac{a e^{a(t+t_0)}}{1+b e^{a(t+t_0)}}
$$

at each point we have a difference

$$
\delta_k(a,b,t_0) = p_k(1+b e^{a(t_k+t_0)})-a e^{a(t_k+t_0)} = p_k+(b p_k-a)e^{a(t_k+t_0)}
$$

so we can build a total squared differences as

$$
E(a,b,t_0) = \sum_{k=1}^n\delta_k^2(a,b,t_0)
$$

and then solve the fitting problem as a minimization one.

$$
\min_{a,b,t_0}E(a,b,t_0)
$$

Comment: Thank you but I'm going to admit that I can't really follow with your used of symbolisation, and I'm not sure of what you meant by minimisation part? Do you mean by optimisation where I find the global minimum point by differentiating? Think of me having the knowledge of a graduate high schooler, since my math skill isn't really strong haha.

Comment: If you have a lot of points, better to fit the logistic formula to the data you have. In this case there are solvers to do that efficiently. Please have a look at the Software item in this reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting